Is it possible to find all pages managed by a page owner?
If we look at Page transparency info of a page we can find a tag that says "Organization name" is responsible for managing this page.
Is there a way to identify all Facebook pages run by an organization? I found two pages manually, and now I would like to find others they are running.

Anybody got any idea how this can be done?
